# Creating a sequence within already existing table and duplicating rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a short table containing:

- Product (Short text)
- Material (Short text)
- Amount (Number)
- From (Number)
- To (Number)

How can I create in MS Access a new column containing a sequence using as boundaries values from columns `From` and `To`? (I tried `concat`, but it returns short text).

On top of that I would like to duplicate all of the values from other columns and paste them to the newly created rows accordingly.

Values `From` and `To` which are my sequence boundaries have no pattern.

[image]

into:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try a calendar/sequence table approach here, in which you inner join a table containing the entire sequence to your current table:

```
SELECT
    t2.Product,
    t2.Material,
    t2.Amount,
    t2.[From],
    t2.[To],
    t1.Sequence
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS Sequence FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources) AS dual
    UNION
    SELECT 2 FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources) AS dual
    UNION
    SELECT 3 FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources) AS dual
    UNION
    SELECT 4 FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources) AS dual
    UNION
    SELECT 5 FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources) AS dual
    UNION
    SELECT 6 FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources) AS dual
    UNION
    SELECT 7 FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources) AS dual
    UNION
    SELECT 8 FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources) AS dual
    UNION
    SELECT 9 FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources) AS dual
    UNION
    SELECT 10 FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources) AS dual
) t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.Sequence BETWEEN t2.[From] AND t2.[To]
ORDER BY
    t1.Sequence;
```

Comment: For your sequence, I prefer `SELECT DISTINCT Abs(ID MOD 10) + 1 FROM MSysObjects` for two reasons: more brief, and `MSysResources` can be empty if someone chooses to delete the default theme.

Comment: @ErikA I'm quite weak as an Access developer.  Good to know there are better ways to generate a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm not fond of relying on using a dataset outside of my control (such as system tables) to generate sequences, and would instead suggest creating a table called `numbers` with a single field called `id` of **Long Integer** data type:

[image]

You can then populate this table with the integers **0** through **9**:

[image]

And use a query such as the following which implements a [cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) (also known as a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)) to yield the numbers 1-100:

```sql
select 10*n10.id+n1.id+1 as n from numbers n1, numbers n10
```

If your sequence is likely to exceed 100, this could become the following to yield the numbers 1-1000:

```sql
select 100*n100.id+10*n10.id+n1.id+1 as n from numbers n1, numbers n10, numbers n100
```

(You can continue to repeat the pattern for the order of magnitude suitable for your data)

With the `numbers` table defined and populated, you can then use the following query to yield the desired result for your data:

```sql
select 
    t.product, t.material, t.amount, t.from, t.to, s.n
from 
    yourtable t, 
    (select 10*n10.id+n1.id+1 as n from numbers n1, numbers n10) s
where 
    s.n between t.from and t.to
order by 
    t.product, s.n
```

(Change `yourtable` to the name of your table)